# Printing Namespace instead of string value

Tags: c#

This method supposed to print the following:

```
Creating r1
-> Assigning r2 to r1
-> Changing values of r2
String = This is new info!, Top = 10, Bottom = 50, Left = 10, Right = 50
String = This is new info!, Top = 10, Bottom = 4444, Left = 10, Right = 50
```

but instead of printing string value it prints the class in which the string is located

```
Creating r1
-> Assigning r2 to r1
-> Changing values of r2
String = Csharp_Projects.Program+ShapeInfo, Top = 10, Bottom = 50, Left =  10, Right = 50
String = Csharp_Projects.Program+ShapeInfo, Top = 10, Bottom = 4444, Left = 10, Right = 50
```

this is the code:

```
 using System;

 namespace Csharp_Projects
{
  static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ShapeInfo.Rectangle.ValueTypeContainingRefType();
   }

   // this class which takes an string as parameter

    public class ShapeInfo
    {
        public string infoString;

        public ShapeInfo(string info)
        {
            infoString = info;
        }

      // this struct has two fields, one is int type  and the other is ShapeInfo (above) and a constructor which set the values

        public struct Rectangle
        {
            public ShapeInfo rectInfo;

            public int recTop, rectleft, rectBottom, rectRight;

            public Rectangle(string info, int top, int left, int Buttom, int Right)
            {
                rectInfo = new ShapeInfo(info);
                recTop = top;
                rectBottom = Buttom;
                rectRight = Right;
                rectleft = left;
            }
            // this method print the results
            public void Display()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("string={0},top={1},Bottom={2},"+"left={3},Right={4}",rectInfo,recTop,rectBottom,rectRight,rectleft);
            }

            // this method make an object and assign it to second variable and then change the values of second variable .

            public static void ValueTypeContainingRefType()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Creating r1");
                Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle("First Rec", 10, 10, 50, 50);
                Console.WriteLine("Assigning r2 to r1");
                Rectangle r2 = r1;
                Console.WriteLine("Change Values of r2");
                r2.rectInfo.infoString = "This is new info!";
                r2.rectBottom = 4444;
                r1.Display();
                r2.Display();
            }


        }
    }
}
  }
```

I really couldn't make out why it happened maybe my knowledge about C# system is not enough, what cause this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't override `.ToString()` in your `ShapeInfo` class, so the system has no way of knowing how you want to print an instance of that class as a string.  By default all objects print their class name (since that's pretty much the only thing every class is guaranteed to have).

Just [override the method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return infoString;
}
```

Comment: which method should take override? because it gives me an error . and btw I inserted the code from very famous book why it didn't mention it there? I mean he got the first print without using override

Comment: @Mohsen: I can't really help with an error you haven't described.  As for your "very famous book", I also can't comment on code I haven't seen.

Comment: thanks anyway for your time. it seems I should study the override concept.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the ToString method in ShapeInfo to return the infoString.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return infoString;
}
```

Or change the your DisplayMethod to use
rectInfo.infoString instead of rectInfo

```
        public void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("string={0},top={1},Bottom={2},"+"left={3},Right={4}",rectInfo.infoString,recTop,rectBottom,rectRight,rectleft);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I notice now that in the book in mentioned your second solution, I just forgot infoString. oh... it was not that hard then